# opencv window not closing after calling destroyAllWindows() function

Tags: python, opencv, tkinter

I am implementing camshift algorithm in python using opencv and using the position given by it to move my mouse and draw on the kolour application.
When i press the button on in tkinter ui a frame launches and then
Upon pressing the key 'q' the 'frame' does not close, The frame just freezes and the option to force quit comes. I am using tkinter for UI.

```
global paint_open
paint_open = 0

def func():

    global frame, roiPts, inputMode ,token

    camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

    cv2.namedWindow("frame")
    cv2.setMouseCallback("frame", selectROI)

    termination = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS | cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_COUNT, 10, 1)
    roiBox = None
    li=[]

    while True:

        (grabbed, frame) = camera.read()

        if roiBox is not None:

            hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
            backProj = cv2.calcBackProject([hsv], [0], roiHist, [0, 180], 1) 

            (r, roiBox) = cv2.CamShift(backProj, roiBox, termination)
            pts = np.int0(cv2.cv.BoxPoints(r))
            li.append(pts)

            #coordinates contain the coordinates of the tracked object
            coordinates = r[0]
            # x, y contains the coordinates
            x = int(coordinates[0])
            y = int(coordinates[1])
            drawing(x,y)     

        #draws a circle around the center from x,y
        cv2.circle(frame, (int(x), int(y)), 4, (0, 0, 255), 2)


        #draws a colored frame around the object
        cv2.polylines(frame, [pts], True, (255, 0, 0), 2)

        #here imshow function start
        cv2.imshow("frame", frame)
        key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF


        # handle if the 'i' key is pressed, then go into ROI
        if key == ord("i") and len(roiPts) < 4:

            inputMode = True
            orig = frame.copy()

            while len(roiPts) < 4:
                cv2.imshow("frame", frame)
                cv2.waitKey(0)
                roiPts = np.array(roiPts)
                s = roiPts.sum(axis = 1)
                tl = roiPts[np.argmin(s)]
                br = roiPts[np.argmax(s)]


            roi = orig[tl[1]:br[1], tl[0]:br[0]]
            roi = cv2.cvtColor(roi, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)



            roiHist = cv2.calcHist([roi], [0], None, [16], [0, 180])
            roiHist = cv2.normalize(roiHist, roiHist, 0, 255, cv2.NORM_MINMAX)
            roiBox = (tl[0], tl[1], br[0], br[1])

        # if the 'q' key is pressed, stop the loop
        elif key == ord("q"):
            break


    camera.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

def drawing(x,y):
    global paint_open
    if paint_open == 0:
        launchapp('kolourpaint')
        paint_open = 1
    py.dragTo(x,y)

def main():
    root=tk.Tk()
    bkgcolor='#D84315'
    root.configure(background=bkgcolor)

    label=tk.Label(root,text="Gesture Recognition Project",font=('arial black',12),fg="white",width=90,height=3,bg="purple")
    label.pack()

    frame1 = tk.Frame(root,bg=bkgcolor)
    frame1.pack(padx=205,pady=25)

    bframe1 = tk.Frame(root,bg=bkgcolor)
    bframe1.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM,padx=205)


    photo3 = tk.PhotoImage(file="3.png")



    button2 = tk.Button(frame1, width=255, height=255, image=photo3,text="Slide Presenter",fg="purple",bg="white",command=func)
    button2.pack(side=tk.LEFT,padx=25)
    button2.image = photo1





# start the event loop
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: There's something wrong with the indentation of your code. It's impossible to tell how much of that code belongs to `func`.

Comment: @BryanOakley i have corrected the indentation please see if you find any mistakes

Answer (score 3):

This question is a bit old but worth answering, since it comes up in searches. I experienced the same problem and eventually found an answer that worked. It seems hack-ish, but allows opencv to go through its processes to close a window. Opencv performs its processing during the waitKey(), so adding a few of those before and after the destroyallwindows() function did the trick.

In your code, where it says

```
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

... try this instead. It worked for me.

```
# All these waitkeys are a hack to get the OpenCV window to close
cv2.waitKey(1)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
for i in range (1,5):
    cv2.waitKey(1)
return
```

Comment: This worked for me, I have several windows and think some windows were opening after the first `destroyAllWindows()` was effective, I gave it "more chances" and works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but `cv` may use `tkinter` to display windows so `root.mainloop()` may keep windows open. You can try to end `root.mainloop()` to close program and all windows.

```
import Tkinter as tk
import cv2

# create global value (with some value)
root = None

def func():
    # inform function to use global variable instead of local one
    global root

    # ...

    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    camera.release()
    # close root window and leave mainloop()
    root.destroy()

def main():
    # inform function to use global variable instead of local one
    global root

    root = tk.Tk()

    # ...

    root.mainloop()

main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Since a new window is opened upon calling *destroyAllWindows()* function, you need to press space-key to close the execution of the command.

Answer (score 0):

This work for me

```
while True: 
    _, frame = cap.read()

    cv2.imshow(windowName, frame)
    keyCode = cv2.waitKey(1)

    if cv2.getWindowProperty(windowName, cv2.WND_PROP_VISIBLE) <1:
        break
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

from https://newbedev.com/closing-video-window-using-close-x-button-in-opencv-python